# Cypher (Neo4j) create relationship to all other nodes (except itself)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created 10 nodes in Neo4j.

How do I quickly and easily create relationships between all of them? (from all, to all, excluding itself and without duplicated relationships?)

For example, if I were to have 3 nodes called A, B, and C:
A - B
A - C
B - C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (n), (m)
WHERE ID(n) < ID(m)
CREATE (n)-[:FOO]->(m)
```

The `WHERE` test ensures that `n` and `m` are different, and also that the same pair is not processed a second time (in reverse order).